SharePoint Online notifcations - wrong language
Issue: SharePoint online is sending email notifications in diferent language in our multi language tenant.
The whole tenant has been created in French, but the sites are configured to English.
Areas: News notifications emails, Shared files/folders emails.
Description:
Our news is being sent in different language, even though the site is configured to English.
What controls the language for all notifications coming from or through SharePoint?
I would like to manage this setting and ensure notifications are sent in English from users.
We tried with multiple users with different outcomes.
PowerShell, API calls, User Profile settings configurations.. all welcome.

The following settings determine the language that is presented to the guest user in the invitation email. These settings are listed in order of precedence. If a setting isn’t configured, the next setting in the list determines the language.

The messageLanguage property of the invitedUserMessageInfo object if
the Create invitation API is used
The preferredLanguage property specified in the guest's user
object
The Notification language set in the properties of the guest
user’s home tenant (for Microsoft Entra tenants only)
The Notification language set in the properties of the resource
tenant.

If none of these settings are configured, the
language defaults to English (US).
Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/invitation-email-elements#how-the-language-is-determined
